# Reportlab: CMYK doesn't work properly when creating colors

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I saw some examples using CMYK but it seems not to be working properly:

```
color = colors.Color(0.00, 0.25, 0.25, 0.01)
```

I tried many colors, but just one looks to be working ok (gray):

```
color = colors.Color(0.01, 0.00, 0.04, 0.20)
```

My code:

```
    from reportlab.lib import colors
    from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, inch, landscape
    from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER
    from reportlab.lib.units import mm
    from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
    from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, LongTable, TableStyle, Paragraph, KeepTogether
    import cgi

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=export.pdf'

    data = [['ID', 'Title', 'Type', 'Priority', 'Status', 'Description', 'Comments']]
    # getting the list
    product_id = request.GET.get('product', '')
    status = request.GET.get('status', '')
    filter_id = request.GET.get('filter', '')
    sort = request.GET.get('sort', '-created')
    author = LdapUser.objects.get(uid=str(request.user))
    issue_list = _get_issue_list(product_id, status, filter_id, author, sort)

    row = 1
    color_style = []
    for issue in issue_list:
        comments = ''
        for comment in issue.comments:
            comments += comment
        data.append([str(issue.id), issue.title, issue.type, issue.priority, issue.status, issue.description, cgi.escape(comments)])
        color = colors.Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
        if issue.status == 'New':
            #color = colors.Color(0.00, 0.25, 0.25, 0.01)
            color = colors.red
        elif issue.status == 'Unconfirmed':
            #color = colors.Color(0.14, 0.14, 0.00, 0.09)
            color = colors.purple
        elif issue.status == 'Confirmed':
            #color = colors.Color(0.00, 0.04, 0.42, 0.00)
            color = colors.yellow
        elif issue.status == 'Triaged':
            #color = colors.Color(0.00, 0.20, 0.48, 0.00)
            color = colors.orange
        elif issue.status == 'Reopened':
            #color = colors.Color(0.24, 0.13, 0.00, 0.00)
            color = colors.lightblue
        elif issue.status == 'Resolved':
            #color = colors.Color(0.14, 0.00, 0.28, 0.04)
            color = colors.palegreen
        elif issue.status == 'Invalid':
            color = colors.Color(0.01, 0.00, 0.04, 0.20)
        #table_style.add('BACKGROUND', (0,row), (-1,row), color)
        color_style.append(('BACKGROUND', (0,row), (-1,row), color))
        row +=1
```

Comment: Could you give a complete example ? not sure what `colors` is here

Comment: @AJK updated with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `colors.Color` uses RGBA type of colors.

here is a verification of this:

```
>>> toColor('rgba( 255,0,0,0.5)') == Color(1,0,0,0.5)
True
>>> toColor('cmyk(1,0,0,0 )') == CMYKColor(1,0,0,0)
True
```

So, you need to use `colors.CMYKColor`